# Opening a PuTTY console with CreateProcess leaves one TCP connection open (but it should've ended)

Tags: c++, winapi, putty

I'm working on a server-client apllication which provides a CLI, I need two instances of this application working first instance acts as server and second instance acts as backup server; both servers are connected through a TCP sockets. In certain situations the role of server and backup server can swap, this can happen writting a swap instruction on the CLI.

I'm connecting to the CLI using PuTTY. **The PuTTY instance is opened inside the application with a call to `CreateProcess`**:

```
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };

// ...

process_information = PROCESS_INFORMATION();

BOOL success = CreateProcess
(
    NULL,
    command, // putty.exe param1 param2
    NULL,
    NULL,
    TRUE,
    DETACHED_PROCESS,
    NULL,
    static_cast<LPCWSTR>(workingDirectory),
    &si,
    &process_information
);
```

But I have a problem with this approach: for some unknown reason if the PuTTY console is open when the server becomes backup server it maintains the TCP listener open and after swapping again it creates a new listener on the same port:

[image]

Then the backup server connects to the previous TCP listener which is not managed by the application anymore so my application acts as if no connection were made.

Here is the catch:

- If I close the PuTTY console the zombie TCP listener closes and then the connection is stablished with the correct listener.
- **If I open the PuTTY console manually (instead of calling `CreateProcess` from inside my application) the TCP listener closes propperly and swapping server roles works perfectly**.

Why opening PuTTY from my application (using `CreateProcess`) prevents the connection to close properly? Is there a way to avoid this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: this is really very well known reason. you create socket handles as inherit. and pass TRUE in bInheritHandles . as result it duplicated to new process. you need use `WSASocketW` with `WSA_FLAG_NO_HANDLE_INHERIT` and - are you really need inherit handles for new process ? if yes - use `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST` for mark handles, which must be inherited

Comment: @RbMm that solved my issue, please make your comment an aswer so I can accept it.