# Create a TRULLY detached process (as if it was opened from outside the main process)

Tags: c++, winapi, putty

Ok, I know that this is a common question already adressed in other threads but please let me add some context:

I'm working on a server-client apllication which provides a CLI, I need two instances of this application working first instance acts as server and second instance acts as backup server; both servers are connected through a TCP sockets. In certain situations the role of server and backup server can swap, this can happen writting a swap instruction on the CLI.

[I'm connecting to the CLI using PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74953750/499359). **The PuTTY instance is opened inside the application with a call to `CreateProcess`**:

```
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };

// ...

process_information = PROCESS_INFORMATION();

BOOL success = CreateProcess
(
    NULL,
    command, // putty.exe param1 param2
    NULL,
    NULL,
    TRUE,
    DETACHED_PROCESS,
    NULL,
    static_cast<LPCWSTR>(workingDirectory),
    &si,
    &process_information
);
```

Doing this call the PuTTY process appears as child of my application process both on task manager and Process Explorer.

[image]

But I have a problem with this approach: for some unknown reason if the PuTTY console is open when the server becomes backup server it maintains the TCP listener open and after swapping again it creates a new listener on the same port, then the backup server connects to the previous TCP listener which is not managed by the application anymore.

Here is the catch:

- If I close the PuTTY console the zombie TCP listener closes and then the connection is stablished with the correct listener.
- **If I open the PuTTY console manually (instead of calling `CreateProcess` from inside my application) the TCP listener closes propperly and swapping server roles works perfectly**.

Until I figure out why opening the PuTTY instance from `CreateProccess` makes my TCP connections behave this way I want to open the PuTTY as if it was NOT opened from within my application.

---

What I've tried so far:

1. Create a batch file that calls PuTTY and `CreateProcess` the batch file (failed).
2. Create a job with `CreateJobObject` and assign the PuTTY process to that job (failed).

The reason behind the #1 try is that I've read that you can create a process (A) that creates a second process (B) and then finishing the first process (A) leaves it orpah, but I wasn't able to make the batch file run at all.

Any help is appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: @273K `ShellExecute`  will call `CreateProcessW` in concrete case - so what sense in use it ?

Comment: @273K - absolute false. not exist parent-child relationship between processes at all. and how i say - in concrete case ShellExecute will call CreateProcessW

Comment: Why does it matter whether your process is listed as the child of another process? The system doesn't use this information for anything meaningful, so why do you care?

Comment: @273K the `ShellExecute` workaround did the trick! Please make your coment an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster - change inheritanhandle from true to false do the trick. Need understand what we doing. But not change something without any understand what we done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ShellExecute, ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch) should do what you want, they don't create parent-child relationships between precesses.